# Bibtex: combining superscript citations and brackets in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing

I would like to combine two citation styles in my document: superscripts in the text (which I have set with `\usepackage[superscript,biblabel]{cite}`), but to display it later in the bibliography with squares. Could you please give me some tips how to do it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[superscript,biblabel]{cite}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@book{A1,
author = {Author, A.},
year = {2001},
title = {Alpha},
}
@book{B2,
author = {Buthor, B.},
year = {2002},
title = {Bravo},
}
@article{C3,
author = {Cuthor, C.},
year = {2003},
title = {Charlie},
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
I am citing these three glorious works \cite{A1, B2, C3}.
\bibliography{test}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\end{document}
```

At the end I would like to have something like this

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation of the `cite` package

[image]

the option `biblabel` defines the bibliography label to match `\cite`, which is what you do *not* want. Remove it and be happy.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[superscript]{cite}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@book{A1,
author = {Author, A.},
year = {2001},
title = {Alpha},
}
@book{B2,
author = {Buthor, B.},
year = {2002},
title = {Bravo},
}
@article{C3,
author = {Cuthor, C.},
year = {2003},
title = {Charlie},
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
I am citing these three glorious works \cite{A1, B2, C3}.
\bibliography{test}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh God... And what weird stuff I have tried.. Thanks!

Comment: @sarma13 I guess this is a sort of initiation rite in TeX: you hang yourself into a problem, try out the most absurd solutions, only to find out that your initial code itself was the origin of the mess. Welcome to TeX.SX!